# MPMoviePlayerController currentPlaybackTime jump while set setCurrentPlaybackTime

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

I am using MPMoviePlayerController as my media player.
I am trying to seek by using my method (movieController is an instance of MPMoviePlayerController)

```
-(void)seekToTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{
    [movieController setCurrentPlaybackTime:time];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(printCurrentPlaybacktime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

as you can see - after seeking I am print out the current playback time rapidly.
The problem is this - at start the current playback time is the actual new time I set.
after some time the current playback time is the old time before changing the playback time,
and after a while it's turn back to the new actual time. the result for the user is that the seek slider is jumping.

this is the log

> 2012-10-02 11:58:24.317 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.321 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.368 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.370 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.372 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.374 Comigo[1067:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamUnlikelyToKeepUp: 1 -> 0
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.375 Comigo[1067:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 1)
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.376 Comigo[1067:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamRanDry: 0 -> 1
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.380 Comigo[1067:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Took background task assertion (9) for playback stall
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.382 Comigo[1067:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 1)
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.383 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.385 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.386 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.387 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.388 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.391 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.395 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.398 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.402 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.405 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.408 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.412 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.415 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.419 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.423 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.425 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.428 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.431 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.435 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.438 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.442 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.445 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.448 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.451 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.455 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.459 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.461 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.465 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3662.729736
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.466 Comigo[1067:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 1)
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.469 Comigo[1067:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.470 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.472 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.482 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.483 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.484 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.487 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.489 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.490 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.495 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.498 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.501 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.505 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.508 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.511 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.515 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.519 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.521 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.525 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.528 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.531 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.535 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.538 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.541 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.545 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.548 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.551 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:24.555 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:25.808 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.061 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.065 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.068 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.071 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.075 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.079 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.081 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.085 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.088 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.091 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.095 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.099 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.101 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.106 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.108 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.111 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.115 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.117 Comigo[1067:907] currentTime 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.120 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.269 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.271 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.275 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.278 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.281 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.285 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.288 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.291 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.295 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.298 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.301 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.305 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.308 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.311 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.315 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.318 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.321 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.325 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.328 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.331 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.335 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.338 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.341 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.345 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.348 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.351 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.355 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.358 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.361 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.365 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.369 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.372 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.375 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.378 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.381 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.385 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.388 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.391 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.395 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.398 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.401 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.405 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.408 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.411 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.415 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.419 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.421 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 956.568935
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.425 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.429 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.431 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.448 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.449 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.450 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.455 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.459 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.461 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.465 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.468 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.472 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.475 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.478 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.481 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.485 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.489 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.491 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.495 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.498 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.501 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.505 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.509 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.511 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.515 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.518 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.521 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.525 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.529 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.531 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.535 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000
>   2012-10-02 11:58:27.538 Comigo[1067:907] print [movieController currentPlaybackTime] = 3660.000000}
>   I delete some rows (because there is a lot of them). so don't pay attention to the log date.
>   thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
[movieController pause]
```

instead?